# Hibernate queries for combination of column values

Tags: hibernate, jpa, database-design, database-schema, hibernate-query

I'm designing a schema for products that have multiple variants:

```java
@Entity
public class Product {
  @Id @GeneratedValue private long id;
  
  @Column(columnDefinition = "JSONB")
  @Type(JsonType.class)
  private List<ProductVariant> variants;
...

@Entity
public class ProductInstance {
  @Id @GeneratedValue private long id;

  @ManyToOne
  private Product product;

  @Column
  private String variantName;
```

I want to be able to query for `ProductInstance`s by specific `(product_id, variant_name)` combinations. I haven't found a straightforward way to do this with JPA Repositories or prepared statements.

I could manually generate sql like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM product_instance 
WHERE (product_id = '1' and variant_name = 'A') 
   OR (product_id = '2' AND variant_name = 'B')
   ...
   OR (product_id = '15' AND variant_name = 'CC');
```

Or I could add a new column that duplicates all the data in the existing `product_id` and `variant_name` columns in order to use a standard JPA Repository:

```
    @Column
    private String productIdVariantName;
```

```java
interface ProductInstanceRepository extends JPARepository<ProductInstance, Long> {
   findByProductIdVariantNameIn(Set<String> combos);
```

1. Are those the 2 best options?
2. Is there a name for this situation/pattern? It seems like it would come up relatively commonly, but I wasn't able to find articles about it or solutions for it.

Answer (score 0):

Since the [Spring Data JPA Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation) does not mention any CONCAT keyword for query creation, you can't do this directly.

You could use a custom query e.g.

```
public interface ProductInstanceRepository extends JpaRepository<ProductInstance, Long> {
    @Query(value="select * from product_instance where product_id || variant_name in :combos", nativeQuery = true)
    List<ProductInstance> findByProductIdVariantNameIn(Set<String> combos);
}
```

or you can use `@Formula` like this

```
public class ProductInstance {
    @Id @GeneratedValue private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private Product product;

    private String variantName;

    @Formula("product_id || variant_name")
    private String productIdVariantName;
}
```

then you could use the query creation provided by spring like this

```
public interface ProductInstanceRepository extends JpaRepository<ProductInstance, Long> {
    List<ProductInstance> findByProductIdVariantNameIn(Set<String> combos);
}
```

Comment: I want to match on `(product_id = ? AND product_variant_name = ?)`. The variant names can be the same across multiple products, so your first suggestion could return ProductInstances that are not correct. There is nothing linking together that a particular product_id is matched with a particular variant_name in the method `findByProductIdInAndVariantNameIn`.

Comment: You are correct, my mistake. I have updated my answer, I hope this works for you.